# Как создать стикерпак aiogram?

Tags: python, django, aiogram

Написал такой код на джанго и айограм:

```
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

@csrf_exempt
def IndexView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("get method not allowed")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jsonRequest = request.body
        jsonRequest = json.loads(jsonRequest)
        jsonStickers = jsonRequest["stickers"]
        ready_stickers = []
        for i in range(len(jsonRequest["stickers"])):
            background = Path("assets", "blanks", jsonStickers[i]["background"] + ".png")
            emoji = Path("assets", "blanks", jsonStickers[i]["emoji"] + ".png")
            text = Path("assets", "blanks", jsonStickers[i]["text"] + ".png")
            
            background_img = Image.open(background)
            emoji_img = Image.open(emoji)
            text_img = Image.open(text)
            background_img.paste(emoji_img, (0, 0), emoji_img)
            background_img.paste(text_img, (0, 0), text_img)
            
            path = Path("assets", "ready", ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(200)) + ".png")
            background_img.save(path)
            ready_stickers.append(InputSticker(sticker=path, emoji_list=["", "", ""]))
            
    name_stickerSet = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(50)) + "_by_" + os.getenv("BOT_NAME")
    reasult = CreateNewStickerSet(user_id=str(os.getenv("USER_ID")), name=name_stickerSet, title=os.getenv("TITLE"), stickers=json.dumps(ready_stickers), sticker_format="static")
    return HttpResponse(reasult)
```

Смысл в том, что отправляется json, в котором содержится задний фон, эмодзи, текст, они все накладываются друг на друга и сохраняются на сервер, а затем отправляются в ТГ и создается стикер пак. Всё было хорошо до этого момента.

Я уже второй день борюсь с документацией, чтобы понять, как это сделать, вечно появляются ошибки на это моменте. Прошу вас, помогите решить проблему.

```
pyton=3.10.9
aiofiles==23.1.0
aiogram @ https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/archive/refs/heads/dev-3.x.zip#sha256=b9cb427ff06e70c37e7331e24a10a6aefee55a8624825780482e78b54c269c15
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
asgiref==3.7.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
Babel==2.9.1
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
Django==4.2.2
djangorestframework==3.14.0
frozenlist==1.3.3
idna==3.4
magic-filter==1.0.9
multidict==6.0.4
Pillow==9.5.0
pydantic==1.10.9
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2023.3
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.6.3
tzdata==2023.3
yarl==1.9.2
```